# How to model dynamic relationships in relational database

Tags: database, relational-database, entity-relationship, data-modeling

I have a data modelling question which certainly occurs often, but unfortunately I could not find suitable resources. I hope you can help me:

I have two Tables

**Departments** = [DepID, Departmentname, ...]

**Employees** = [EmplID, Name, Adress, ...]

**EmployeesAtDepartment** = [EmplID, DepID]

Here, the table **EmployeesAtDepartment** shall create a relationship between each employee and the department(s) she works at (mostly only one, but it may be possible to belong to more than one department).

Employees may change departments over time. I need not only to know the current state of the Employee - Department relationship, but also determine the state at any given point in the past.

Now comes my question: What concepts are available to model these 'time varying relationships' in a relational database?

My first-guess is to add additional two date columns to **EmployeesAtDepartment**, e.g [StartedAtDate, QuitAtDate], where the latter is NULL if the employee currently works in the department. In this case, only changes are saved in the database.

Another approach would be to save the whole state of **EmployeesAtDepartment** for each date, i.e. add one column [Date]. In this case the data is stored highly redundantly, but it makes it quite easy to determine the employee-department relationship for a given day.

Can you recommend any resources on the pros and cons of the above mentioned approaches or are there even better ways?

Thanks!

Comment: *Tables* represent relation(ship)s/associations. As in "relational" & "entity-relationship" models. Base tables are table variables. A query returns rows satisfying a relationship given in terms of base table relationships. For rows satisfying a relationship ".... on date [d]" have a date column d. (FKs are wrongly called "relationships" by presentations/methods/products that don't understand the RM & the ERM.) Dozens of published academic textbooks on information modeling & database design are online free in pdf. stanford.edu has a free online course. Your topic is "temporal" data/DBs.

Comment: thanks for the comment. using "temporal db" I found https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slowly_changing_dimension, which is very helpful to me.

Comment: Asking for off-site resources is off-topic. You could ask a specific question about given specific designs. [ask] Nevertheless also: This is a faq. Please always google many clear, concise & specific versions/phrasings of your question/problem/goal with & without your particular strings/names & read many answers. Add relevant keywords you discover to your searches. If you don't find an answer then post, using 1 variant search as title & keywords for tags. See the downvote arrow mouseover text. When you do have a non-duplicate code question to post please read & act on [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

It's worth thinking through the various use cases.

Your first model is instinctively right - it doesn't duplicate data. It also makes it easy-ish to answer questions like "at which date did person X move from department y?", "how many people changed department between dates a and b", "how many people were in department x on date y", "what's the longest period anyone remained in a department".

It also allows you to attach further details to department changes - reason codes, comments, etc.

Finally, it feels much easier to manage - you don't need a scheduled job to copy the daily version of the data.

Your second option has as its benefit the fact you can forget a single where clause from one of your queries (who was in department x at date y). I don't think it's worth the trade-off - especially because figuring out some of the questions above becomes rather difficult